# Bootstrap - Highcharts not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I downloaded Highcharts files and put it on my webserver.
When I open a highchart example file, it works and the highchart is being created. When I "include" a working highchart php file to my bootstrap "index.php", then it doesnt seem to work and its just blank.
As soon as I want to have a highchart in a bootstrap site, its blank.

I tried creating highcharts without including them to the bootstrap file, and then they work normally. But as soon as I want to create or include a highchart to my bootstrap page, it is just a blank page.

Any idea?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Check that you might miss jquery.js or might the hightcharts.js is included before the jquery.js. It should render after jquery.js.

Comment: You are my Hero. Worked like a Charm. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working here even the bootstrap js file is included. Please check the order of the scripts in view source. The highchart js might render before jquery.js

```js
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
   title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
    x: -20 //center
   },
   subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
    x: -20
   },
   xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
     'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
   },
   yAxis: {
    title: {
     text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    },
    plotLines: [{
     value: 0,
     width: 1,
     color: '#808080'
    }]
   },
   tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: '°C'
   },
   legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    borderWidth: 0
   },
   series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
   }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
   }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
   }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
   }]
  });
 });
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script><script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: The jquery.js file did in fact render after the highchart.js, thats why it didnt work. Changed the order and now works like a charm.

Comment: @N1njaWTF Welcome :)